# txt file and linebreaks

Tags: command-line, libreoffice, vim, nano

I used

antiword >filename.txt

To convert a .doc word document to a txt file. Then I edited the file in nano (also tried vim) and when the document is viewed in libre office and gvim or even text edit the line breaks are in the wrong place. The bit that was originally a .doc kept the correct line breaks but the bit I added did not. It displays correctly in the terminal editors but not in the GUI

A link to an example:

B was written in  libre office C was written in nano.

http://pastebin.com/jshWMiih

Why is that so? 
Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: It would help if you uploaded the text file to [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/), and then left a comment with a link to the text file so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Sorry, http://pastebin.com/jshWMiih. Its not the worst one but its the only one that I have where I have not manually changed the formatting later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mistaken *word wrap* for *line breaks*.

Compare:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

to

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

The first text is not word-wrapped while second one is wrapped to become more readable. In the source code of this answer, you can see the same text though. In order to make the text appear with consistent line breaks, provide the line breaks yourself (i.e., hit 

Enter

`vim` automatically breaks lines if you have `textwidth` (shorthand: `tw`) set (in normal mode, type `:set tw=80` followed by Enter

 to have at most 80 characters on one line.). On your existing text, you can type `gg` to go to the beginning of your document followed by `gqG` to wrap from the current position to the end.

I have taken an alternative approach, the text was saved to a file `foo.txt` and I executed the `fold -s foo.txt > foo-new.txt` to get the below text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis 
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu 
fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in 
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

For more information about the tools I have used:

- vim textwidth setting: `vim +h\ tw`
- "Wrap each input line to fit in specified width": `man fold`